# Search Users in Active Directory based on First Name, Last Name and Display Name

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal, principalcontext, principalsearcher

I trying to search my organization Active directory for users.

If the FirstName **or** LastName **or** DisplayName matches a particular string value, it should return the users.

**My Code:**

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.GivenName = "Ramesh*";
// qbeUser.Surname = "Ramesh*";
// qbeUser.DisplayName= "Ramesh*";    

PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    //
}
```

The problem is that I am able to search by only one filter.

I am able to AND the filters but not OR. Whether any solutions are available?

Comment: See [a possible solution for this issue here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195124/ambiguous-name-resolution-anr-ma-equivalent-in-net-3-5-directoryservices-ac) - using the extensibility of `UserPrincipal` to get access to the `anr` property (ambiguous name resolution) which allows searches in multiple name-related properties

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for the solution. It's working correctly. Can you post this as a answer. So that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See a possible solution for this issue in this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195124/ambiguous-name-resolution-anr-ma-equivalent-in-net-3-5-directoryservices-ac).

You will need to use the extensibility of `UserPrincipal` to create a descendant class, in order to get access to the `anr` property (anr = ambiguous name resolution) which allows searches in multiple name-related properties at once.

Comment: This link(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223243.aspx) helped me the find more about Ambiguous Name Resolution(ANR).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DirectorySearcher.
[This article](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/05/ldap-search-filter-examples.html) may help.