# Teams Messages Beta Endpoint - Calling this API using MSGraph Application Permissions is not supported

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I attempt to use teams beta endpoints such as

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{group-id}
```

with application only access I receive the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Calling this API using MSGraph Application Permissions is not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "32ea3e82-d0c5-42ce-9e94-b215bf255a0a",
            "date": "2018-08-20T20:52:12"
        }
    }
}
```

These endpoints work fine with user delegated permissions. Is this type of access truly not supported, or am I missing something in the request? My end goal is to query teams channel messages without user interaction.

---

Updating with additional details on getting token and other endpoints:

I am getting consent with
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent`, then getting the token with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`. I am using the Client Credentials grant type.

If I try to navigate deeper into the teams endpoint (e.g. channels or messages), I get:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "953fd07b-6e4e-4ce2-bd97-92a9eaa676bf",
            "date": "2018-08-22T13:37:08"
        }
    } 
}
```

I also tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{group-id}/`, which returns expected results, but `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{group-id}/team` returns the `Calling this API using MSGraph Application Permissions is not supported` error.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suppose you want to query teams channel messages.

Following [this documentation](http://%20https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_list_messages), we can retrieve the list of messages in the channel of the team.

we need the delegated permissions like `Group.Read.All` and `Group.ReadWrite.All` for the work or school account. The Application permissions is not supported.

If we want query teams channel messages without user interaction, we can use [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_servic) to get an access token.

Then we can use access token to query teams channel message without user interaction.

For more detail about how to get  an access token without a user, we can review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790362/c-sharp-mvc-and-ms-graph-questions/51819670#51819670).

Comment: I followed the documentation on access without user interaction by getting admin consent. I also verified that the appropriate permissions were granted. The error above was the result. I am able to access other endpoints without user interaction, but teams endpoints are not working. Is access to teams API without user interaction not available?

Comment: I think he can apply to the team endpoint, can you provide more detailed response information?

Comment: That is the only response I get. I am getting consent with https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent , then getting the token with https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token . I am using the Client Credentials grant type. If I try to navigate deeper into the teams endpoint (e.g. channels or messages), I get: {
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "e8948429-4518-4a51-bca1-a142bdced3fd",
            "date": "2018-08-22T13:24:36"
        }
    }
}

Comment: I reviewed the content and the comment we posted, and I carefully read  [ this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/zh-cn/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_list_messages), and found that it does not support the Application Permissions